# Simple file with polymorphism compilation problem

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I have problem with compile some very simple code and I don't know what is wrong with it :/
Take a look:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void func() {};
};

int main()
{
    A* obj = new B();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the message I get from g++:

```
Info: resolving vtable for _cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info by 
    linking to __imp __ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE (auto-import) 
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info by 
    linking to __imp___Z TVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (auto-import) 
k:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
warning: auto-importing has been activated without 
    --enable-auto-import specified on the c ommand line. This should work 
    unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from 
    auto-imported DLLs
```

Comment: What platform? What compiler? What is the error message? FWIW, it compiles for me using Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: You're not going to get anywhere asking questions like this. Try to solve it yourself first, and then tell us what's going wrong and what you've tried.

Comment: The code is OK and compiles without any problems. So, if you "have problem with compile", you have to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: I get from g++ this message: Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info by linking to __imp_
__ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info by linking to __imp___Z
TVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (auto-import)
k:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: a
uto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the c
ommand line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
 from auto-imported DLLs.

Comment: I added the message from your comment to the question. However, there does not seem to be any error in there. Do you have any unexpected behavior?

Comment: Works on ideone with g++4.3 - http://www.ideone.com/ESmvi Maybe this is because you don't have virtual destructor?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any problems with compiling, you have problems (more precisely, just warnings) with linking. See:

```
d:\alqualos\pr\testpq>g++ -Wall -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:8: warning: unused variable 'obj'
d:\alqualos\pr\testpq>g++ -Wall main.o
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info by linking to __imp_
__ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info by linking to __imp___Z
TVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (auto-import)
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: a
uto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the c
ommand line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
 from auto-imported DLLs.
```

This is a widely encountered "feature" of MinGW. It happens if your program needs anything from the standard C++ library, even simply std::cout. In this case it has something to do with vtables. To get rid of it:

```
d:\alqualos\pr\testpq>g++ -Wall -Wl,--enable-auto-import main.o
```

I have no idea what "should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from auto-imported DLLs" means. I have tried googling it but haven't found anything useful. If anyone figures out what it really means and when it could be dangerous, please post an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

try `A * obj = new B;`, however in the future please post the error message as well.

Comment: Standart says that there is no difference between new B and new B().

Comment: True, but some compilers might get confused.

Comment: @Mihran: well, as of C++03 `new B;` does default initialization whereas `new B();` does value initialization, since B is a non-POD class. But since `B` has no data members or user-defined constructors, it makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: There is a slight difference. `new B` does default initialization, while `new B()` does zero initialization. Thought the differences are minor and really only apply if their is no user defined copy constructor on the class or any parent or and child or any parents child.

Answer (score 0):

The code that your post here meets all requirements of C++ standart. So problem is in compiler, I've tried to compile it in VS(Windows) and g++(Linux), and in both of them compilation successed.

Answer (score 0):

I test this on another computer and it's working, so I think problem is with compilator on one computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried to add virtual destructor to base class? Maybe this will help.